# user-type not defined Worksheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have tried to add references to my project so I can get this error solved but I haven't been successful.

Could anyone please tell me which libraries should I add?

```
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = Worksheets.Add

 'Get the folder object associated with the directory
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\")
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "The files found in " & objFolder.Name & "are:"

 'Loop through the Files collection
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
    MyFile = objFile.Name
      NewName = getNewFileName()
```

Comment: You are using late binding so you don't need to add references (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115).  Where is the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are working **within Word IDE** then go to **Tools -> References** and browse for **Microsoft Excel [version number] Object Library**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged the question **word-vba**, but you are using the `Worksheets` reference, which is part of Excel.

If you really are using the `Worksheets` reference in Word you would get the `User-defined type not defined`-error.

If not, something else is missing and you need to tell us more. What line does the error highlight etc.